# Why does Python follow symlinks? How do I work around that?

Tags: python, linux, git, python-2.7, symlink

This is my directory layout:

```
projects/
   +-projectA/
     |---moduleA.py
     |---script.py -> ../projectB/script.py
   +-projectB/
     |---script.py
```

This is what script.py contains:

```
import moduleA
print "hello there"
```

Here's what I'm doing:

```
$ pwd
[...]/projects/projectA

$ python2 script.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "script.py", line 1, in <module>
    import moduleA
ImportError: No module named moduleA
```

The reason for this layout is that project A and project B are both from **git** repositories and get updated every once in a while. However, I write projectB and want to edit and push it, while not having to copy files over (it relies on stuff in project A).

Having it as a **submodule**/part of projectA is not an option, since the script has dependencies the maintainer of project A doesn't want.

The reverse is also not an option, since it's also so small in relation that it doesn't warrant adding project A (which is large and actually many different modules) as a submodule in project B, which would also create unnecessary extra files. Additionally, users are mainly be in project A's directory so a submodule would not make sense anyway.

I also don't want to use **hard links** for obvious reasons. I also can't do something like

```
sys.path.append("../projectA")
```

in script.py, because other users of script.py probably don't have the same directory layout as me, and some will download it straight to projectA (without cloning).

**So first of all**, why does the python interpreter follow that symlink, and not execute the code as if it was in projectA's directory?

**And secondly**, how can I solve this problem with the caveats stated above?

(Feel free to also just answer a single of the two above questions.)

Comment: I'm not sure you read what I wrote. Shell scripts work as I expect. Python scripts don't. If I'm in projectA's directory with a shell script inside that is actually a symlink to somewhere else, that shell script will behave as if it were in project A's directory. So what do you mean, "expected behaviour"?

Comment: Example: http://pastebin.kde.org/pfzj1nwgl

Comment: if `projectB` depends on `moduleA.py` then you should install `moduleA` in the environment where you need to run scripts from `projectB`. `pip install -e` would install in editable mode.

Answer (score 3):

I just run into the same "surprise" today with python3.9 -- so at least python ecosystem seems to be stable and upward compatible. ;)

For another surprise, using `PYTHONPATH=.` "fixes" that behaviour!
I would have guessed that only `PYTHONPATH=$PWD` would do the job, no idea why `PYTHONPATH=.` is fine too. ;)

```
$ python3.9 symlink.py  #  this breaks with "import local_module" -- ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'local_module'
$ PYTHONPATH=.    python3.9 symlink.py # works
$ PYTHONPATH=$PWD python3.9 symlink.py # works
```

I still do not like that "solution" (not yet?), so right now that work/test directory now doesn't use any symlinks anymore -- all stuff now gets copied/rsynced into the test dir. :-(

Comment: Another alternative is to import the script as a module. E.g. `$ python3.9 -m symlink`